# Exporting list of URLs

Tags: core-service, web8.5, importexportservice

In SDL Web 8.5 is it possible to export a list of all URLs in a specific tree?

We're hoping to use this to cross-check an XML sitemap to ensure nothing that's live isn't missed out (as crawlers won't index anything with a direct link to it).

Thank you,

Answer (score 8):

There is no 'out of the box' way via the GUI, but you can do this using the Core Service.

Something like the following code (which outputs a CSV) should give you a good start:

```
void Main()
{
    List<PageData> allPages = Client.GetList("tcm:25-1234-4", new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData { Recursive = true, ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Page } }).Cast<PageData>().ToList();    
    foreach (PageData page in allPages)
    {
        OutputPageDetails(page.Id);
    }
}

void OutputPageDetails(string pageId)
{
    PageData page = (PageData)Client.Read(pageId, null);
    string livePagePublishUrl = Client.GetPublishUrl(pageId, "Live");
    Console.WriteLine($"{pageId}, \"{page.Title}\", \"{livePagePublishUrl}\"");
}
```

(P.S. You'll probably want to consider using `Client.GetListXML()`, rather than `Cleint.GetList()` for efficiency)

Comment: Generally speaking, `GetListXML` is not more efficient than `GetList` (as a matter of fact, the first one internally calls the second and then builds the list XML).

Comment: I assume the example TCM URI (`tcm:25-1234-64`) should actually be the ID (TCM URI or WebDAV URL) of a Publication rather than a Page ?

Comment: Good point, Rick. It should’ve been the TcmId of a Structure Group where we’re starting from (rather than a page). I’ve updated it now

Comment: That’s interesting about ‘GetListXML()’ calling ‘GetList()’ internally. My concern was more about the amount of data coming ‘over the wire’ when working with a large list of objects (when using ‘GetList()’). I’ve never actually compared the two sizes though.

Comment: The amount of data for both types of lists can be optimized using the `ListBaseColumns` and `AdditionalColumns` properties of the list filter. In general, `GetList` results in so-called R6 XML going over the wire, whereas `GetListXML` results in R5 XML. The latter is older, but a bit more compact (it heavily uses XML attributes rather than nested XML elements).  So, indeed, `GetList` will result in a bit more data sent over the wire, but in many situations this is neglectable.

Comment: BTW: In this particular example, the difference between the two list types is for sure neglectable, given the fact that for each list item, two additional Core Service roundtrips are done, one of which reading the entire Page (in R6 XML format).  :-)

Comment: They’re really good points. It’d be good to get some speed and network stats for various common examples so we can all start making the right choices of which to select when.

Answer (score 3):

Actually Jonathan's answer is just part of the solution. You should create 2 lists:

1. first list is the list created using Core Service API and this list
   is the list of URLs for pages that CM side thinks that are
   published.
2. Second list is list of page URLs created using Content Delivery API, and this list is the list of actually published pages.

In ideal world, these 2 lists should be identical, but in most cases they are not. Second list is the list of actually published pages on CD Environment, so you should in any case do the following:

- Create both lists
- compare them and make sure that they are in sync (if there are some URLs in first but not in second list, republish the page so that it indeed comes to CD side. If there is URL in second, but not in first list, it means that item is orphan, so you should create undeploy package and remove it from CD environment).